# Can the mains voltage affect laser intensity?

Tags: voltage, power

First of all in very new to the photonics field and i am only venturing into it because I have to troubleshoot an experiment and the issue seems to be the optics block.

So i am using an instrument that uses laser induced fluorescence to detect molecules. The issue is that we have two instruments based in two sites, one in america (110V mains) and the other in europe (230V mains). We noticed that the european unit needs to have the laser gains increased a lot to be able to have a similar output as the american unit.

We are trying to design a universal calibration for the experiment to work equally in both sites.

Is it known if that difference in mains power would have such an effect on the laser output?

Otherwise what could be the issue?

Cheers

Comment: It is always possible that one unit or the other is not fully up to snuff, but there is a lot of circuitry between the power mains and the actual power going to the laser head and one would like to think that there was reasonable feedback. The other possibility of course is that one head is better aligned or has higher reflectivity mirrors, or any number of other laser issues are just better...

Comment: I would assume that trading laser heads isn't an easy thing to do...

Comment: I agree with Jon that there is a lot going on inside a laser system, and as long as both mains voltages are within spec, this should not be the problem. It would be hard to diagnose the issue without knowing more, e.g. what kind of laser is it, what diagnostics have already been run, etc., but generically, dirty optics, poorly aligned optics, and failing parts (flashlamps, laser diodes) are common causes of low laser output.

Comment: What laser are you using? By output do you mean the laser output or the fluorescence output?